# Android Toolbar and SlidingTabLayout size

Tags: android, android-tablayout, pagerslidingtabstrip

I'm having an issue with the size of my SlidingTabLayout. I have the function working and will resize on scroll if required, in this case I don't want my SlidingTabLayout to resize, I want it small like the below:-

[image: What I want]

This is what it currently looks like:-

[image: What it looks like right now]

I have tried numerous approaches to this but keep hitting a dead end. Can anyone explain?

Here is my code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragmentCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragmentToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <com.photonapps.yesorno.navdrawer.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentSlidingTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/fragmentViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

TabStip

```
class
SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 2;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 2;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFFFFFFFF;

private static final int DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 1;
private static final byte DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x00;
private static final float DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT = 0.5f;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

private final Paint mDividerPaint;
private final float mDividerHeight;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue,
            true);
    final int themeForegroundColor = outValue.data;

    mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer
            .setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setDividerColors(setColorAlpha(
            Color.WHITE, DEFAULT_DIVIDER_COLOR_ALPHA));

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();

    mDividerHeight = DEFAULT_DIVIDER_HEIGHT;
    mDividerPaint = new Paint();
    mDividerPaint
            .setStrokeWidth((int) (DEFAULT_DIVIDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density));
}

void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
    mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
    invalidate();
}

void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setDividerColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final int dividerHeightPx = (int) (Math.min(
            Math.max(0f, mDividerHeight), 1f) * height);
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f
                && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer
                    .getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset)
                    * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() + (1.0f - mSelectionOffset)
                    * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height,
            mBottomBorderPaint);

    // Vertical separators between the titles
    int separatorTop = (height - dividerHeightPx) / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount - 1; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        mDividerPaint.setColor(tabColorizer.getDividerColor(i));
        canvas.drawLine(child.getRight(), separatorTop, child.getRight(),
                separatorTop + dividerHeightPx, mDividerPaint);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha}
 * value.
 */
private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color),
            Color.blue(color));
}

/**
 * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
 * 
 * @param ratio
 *            of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will
 *            give an even blend, 0.0 will return {@code color2}.
 */
private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio)
            + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio)
            + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio)
            + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements
        SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;
    private int[] mDividerColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }

    @Override
    public final int getDividerColor(int position) {
        return mDividerColors[position % mDividerColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }

    void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
        mDividerColors = colors;
    }
}
   }
```

This is the SlidingTabLayout

```
    public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position}
     *         is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    /**
     * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of
     *         {@code position}.
     */
    int getDividerColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);

    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 * 
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and
 * {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors
 * are treated as a circular array. Providing one color will mean that all
 * tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for tab dividers. These colors are treated as
 * a circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are
 * indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setDividerColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using
 * {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are required to set any
 * {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
 * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
 * 
 * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
 */
public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 * 
 * @param layoutResId
 *            Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId
 *            id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}

/**
 * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the
 * pager content (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this
 * call has been made.
 */
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab
 * view is not set via {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the
        // Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed
        // state
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground, outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the
        // Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate
            // it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip, false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView
                    .findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (tabTitleView != null) tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0
            || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure
            // we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0)
                || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null) ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle
                .getWidth()) : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position,
                    positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: post your style.xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use TabLayout from [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)? In my own experience I found it better from both visual and simplicity of usage perspective.

Add to your `build.gradle` dependencies closure:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

Replace your SlidingTabLayout in XML with this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Grab it in your Java code:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
```

Comment: Thanks xAF. I have successfully implemented this style, however struggled again to have the ViewPager & Tablayout within fragments. Essentiall what I am trying to create is the viewpager in fragments rather than in the main activity. I would like a MainActivity with a navigation drawer, then fragments only with viewpagers.

Comment: @PhillWiggins, I've done something like that previously. I'll post a question and answer precisely about how to implement Activity with navigation drawer and nested Fragments, some of which make use of TabLayout. I'll post a link under this answer

Comment: Amazing, looked for a few examples but kept stumbling myself. Would really appreciate!

Comment: @PhillWiggins, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815193/how-do-i-implement-appcompatactivity-with-navigationdrawer-and-multiple-fragment/35815194#35815194

Comment: Cheers mate! I'll give that a go now. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Tried your code with success. Excellent. Thanks for that!

Comment: Very glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problemm until i tried this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the result for me:

[image]

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @helldawg13. I have tried this approach, adding 


            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"

But this will still open the app with the larger Tabs height, when scrolled it goes to the height I am looking for. It's just starting the app with that in place that I'm having issues with.

Comment: check the height of the TabLayout on my example and the height of SlidingTabStrip on yours

Comment: Yep, I've changed that too. It's strange. I can't work this out?

Comment: are you using the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` ?

Comment: No, SlidingTabLayout as I had a few issues with the TabLayout. Mainly fragment related issues. The codes above for the SlidingTabLayout. It's weird. It's like that starting state of the SlidingTabLayout is too large. When scrolling it is reduced to the size I am looking for. It's just trying to set the initial height that I am struggling with

Comment: why dont you use the TabLayout?what issues did you have?

Comment: I had issues with the visibility of the TabLayout and the Toolbar. The ViewPager was working fine, but visibility and functionality of the TabLayout was lost when switching between fragments.